# Спрятать значек отсутствия изображения

Tags: html, css, изображения

При отсутствия изображения, на которое ссылаетя тег img должен быть желтый фон. Проблема в том, что на мобильных и MS Edge показывается значек отсутствия изображения.

```css
img {
  margin-right: 16px;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  object-fit: contain;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <!-- <img src='./images/img0.png' srcset="./images/img0@2x.png 2x, ./images/img0@3x.png 3x" alt='' width=48 height=48/> -->
  <img src='./images/img0.svg' alt='' width=48 height=48/>
  <figcaption></figcaption>
</figure>
```

Как его убрать?

Comment: а JavaScript решение подойдет?

Comment: @IliaBrykin спасибо, нет. только css/html/less